# Restore Missing Project Contents in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, restore

I have created an Android project using Eclipse Juno for long time. Accidentally when i imported that project to my workspace, i checked "Copy project into workspace" while it has been already in the workspace. Surprisingly, all the file inside the project, such as class, resources, manifest become empty!

I'm still wondering what actually the main cause of this. Anyone here ever faced the same problem? I need some workarounds, because the project is very important to me and i have no backup.